# default row one for one set of rows in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

```
CREATE TABLE ContactInfo (
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
CompanyID int NOT NULL, 
ContactName varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
IsPrimary bit DEFAULT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

INSERT INTO ContactInfo (CompanyID,ContactName,IsPrimary) VALUES (1,'Vijay',1);
INSERT INTO ContactInfo (CompanyID,ContactName,IsPrimary) VALUES (1,'Amit',0);

ID  CompanyID   ContactName IsPrimary
1   1           Vijay       1
2   1           Amit        0
```

Whenever user adds, updates and deletes rows, for each company `IsPrimary` should be unique. I.e for each `CompanyID` there should be only one row that has `IsPrimary = 1`.

**Conditions:**

1. only one row should be `IsPrimary = 1`  for each `CompanyID`
2. all rows should not be `IsPrimary = 0` for each `CompanyID`
3. if user deletes `IsPrimary` row then other row should be assigned `IsPrimary = 1`
4. when first time user enter the record user will select isprimary,  even if he forget our query should assign isprimary =1'
   5 when entering onward second   record if he assign isPrimary=1 if isprimary exist in same company id then that record should be isprimary = 0'
   6.if existing isprimary change 1 to 0 then other top 1 record under same company id that should be assign isprimary=1.'

I hope you understand my condition

i also put question in msdn  [enter link description here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/87abf0ea-dc25-4a4d-895d-9dc028f71106/default-row-one-for-one-set-of-rows-in-sql-server?forum=transactsql)

some body give near solution but it's working with all condition

```
CREATE TABLE ContactInfo (
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
CompanyID int NOT NULL, 
ContactName varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
IsPrimary bit DEFAULT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER trg1  ON ContactInfo  AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
    --UPDATE ContactInfo SET IsPrimary=1 FROM ContactInfo JOIN inserted I ON I.CompanyID=.ContactInfo.CompanyID
    --for INSERT 
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
       UPDATE T SET IsPrimary= CASE WHEN RN=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CompanyID ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) RN,IsPrimary 
       FROM ContactInfo WHERE CompanyID IN(SELECT CompanyID FROM inserted)) T

    --for UPDATE
    ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
       UPDATE T SET IsPrimary= CASE WHEN RN=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CompanyID ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) RN,IsPrimary 
       FROM ContactInfo WHERE CompanyID IN(SELECT CompanyID FROM inserted)) T

    --for DELETE
    ELSE
       UPDATE T SET IsPrimary= CASE WHEN RN=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CompanyID ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) RN,IsPrimary 
       FROM ContactInfo WHERE CompanyID IN(SELECT CompanyID FROM deleted)) T
GO 


--insert one row with is primary 0
INSERT INTO ContactInfo (CompanyID,ContactName,IsPrimary) VALUES (1,'Vijay',0);
--IsPrimary gets 1 actually
SELECT * FROM ContactInfo

--add one more row for the same company id 1 with IsPrimary=1
INSERT INTO ContactInfo (CompanyID,ContactName,IsPrimary) VALUES (1,'Amit',1);
--IsPrimary gets 0 actually
SELECT * FROM ContactInfo

--update the Isprimary to 1 for Amit
UPDATE ContactInfo SET IsPrimary=1 WHERE CompanyID=1 and ContactName='Amit'
SELECT * FROM ContactInfo

--delete Vijay whose IsPrimary=1
DELETE ContactInfo WHERE CompanyID=1 and ContactName='Vijay'
--Amit's Isprimary has been set 1
SELECT * FROM ContactInfo
```

Comment: You need to implement trigger. What have you tried? Can you show the code?

Comment: i am planing to do  like this  -- for new insert if not selected Primary
if not EXISTS(select isprimary from ContactInfo where CompanyID= 1 and IsPrimary = 1)
begin 
 UPDATE ContactInfo 
 SET     IsPrimary = 1  
end

Comment: @naweez I don't really get you here. The trigger looks OK to me. Can you describe the case where it doesn't work?

Comment: You could just do a union for inserted and deleted tables without that confusing logic

Comment: The design of `IsPrimary` is inappropriate, you shouldn't rely on trigger to maintain the field and suffer from possible locking. Instead you add a `CreateDate` field and `ForcePrimaryDate` then calculate the `IsPrimary` on the fly from a view

Answer (score 0):

Provided trigger does the job partially, but does not allow you to control how to handle what happens to IsPrimary flag when you delete the last from the group or have multiple IsPrimary-s due to INSERTs or UPDTEs.

In order to simplify testing a little bit, I have changed ContactInfo a little bit - `IsPrimary` get a default of 0, since all but one record have 1 here:

```
-- drop table ContactInfo
CREATE TABLE ContactInfo (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CompanyID int NOT NULL, 
    ContactName varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    IsPrimary bit NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)
)
GO
```

Now, the new trigger:

Basically, I am trying to handle the following cases:

no primary in group - add to one in the group
more than one primary in the group
   if primary comes from inserted, use that
   else use from actual table

```
 alter TRIGGER trg1  ON ContactInfo  AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
 AS
 BEGIN
    DECLARE @Debug BIT = 1

    -- ContactInfo now contains data as if operation is done
    CREATE TABLE #tmpTrg1 (CompanyID INT PRIMARY KEY, MinId INT, PrimaryCount INT)

    -- if primary count for a company is 1, it is fine, no need for extra operations
    INSERT INTO #tmpTrg1
    (CompanyID, PrimaryCount, MinId)
    SELECT CompanyID, COUNT(IsPrimary), MIN(ID)
    FROM ContactInfo
    GROUP BY CompanyID
    HAVING COUNT(*) <> 1

    IF (@Debug = 1)
        select '#tmpTrg1' AS '#tmpTrg1', * from #tmpTrg1

    -- no primary count
    -- try to avoid putting IsPrimary back again if caller wants to get rid of it
    update CI
    set IsPrimary = 1
    FROM ContactInfo CI
        JOIN #tmpTrg1 T ON T.CompanyID = CI.CompanyID AND T.MinId = CI.ID
    where ISNULL(T.PrimaryCount, 0) = 0 AND
        ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM inserted)

    -- still no primary, choosing one from each group
    ;WITH CntCte AS (
        SELECT CompanyID, MIN(ID) AS MinId
        FROM ContactInfo
        GROUP BY CompanyID
        HAVING MAX(CAST(IsPrimary AS INT)) = 0)
    update CI
    set IsPrimary = 1
    FROM ContactInfo CI
        JOIN CntCte C ON C.CompanyID = CI.CompanyID AND C.MinId = CI.ID

    -- too many primary counts - removing IsPrimary from all except one. A primary from inserted takes precedence
    ;WITH InsCte AS (
        SELECT CompanyID, MIN(ID) AS MinId
        FROM inserted CI
        GROUP BY CompanyID),
    MinInsCte AS (
        SELECT T.CompanyID, ISNULL(InsCte.MinId, T.MinId) AS MinId
        FROM #tmpTrg1 T
            LEFT JOIN InsCte ON InsCte.CompanyID = T.CompanyID AND T.PrimaryCount > 1)
    UPDATE CI
    SET CI.IsPrimary = 0
    FROM ContactInfo CI
        JOIN MinInsCte Ins ON Ins.CompanyID = CI.CompanyId AND Ins.MinId <> CI.ID
END
GO
```

And the tests:

```
truncate table ContactInfo
go

-- first records should be primary
INSERT INTO ContactInfo (CompanyID,ContactName) VALUES (1,'Some name 1'), (2, 'Some name 2')
SELECT 'first records', * FROM ContactInfo
GO

-- multiple insert - should not get primary
INSERT INTO ContactInfo (CompanyID,ContactName) VALUES (2,'Vijay'), (3, 'Other name'), (2, 'Extra name')
SELECT 'multiple insert', * FROM ContactInfo
GO

-- update should not affect primary
update ContactInfo SET ContactName = 'new name for non primary #1' where CompanyID = 2
SELECT 'update non primary', * FROM ContactInfo
GO

update ContactInfo SET ContactName = 'new name for primary' where CompanyID = 1
SELECT 'update primary', * FROM ContactInfo
GO

-- deleting existing primary
delete ContactInfo WHERE ID = 2
SELECT 'delete primary', * FROM ContactInfo
GO

-- try to remove primary from existing record
update ContactInfo SET IsPrimary = 0 where ID = 1
SELECT 'remove primary', * FROM ContactInfo

-- multiple deletes
DELETE ContactInfo
WHERE CompanyID IN (2, 3)
SELECT 'multiple delete, including primary', * FROM ContactInfo

-- insert another record with primary
INSERT INTO ContactInfo (CompanyID,ContactName, IsPrimary) VALUES (2,'Other primary', 1)
SELECT 'insert another record with primary', * FROM ContactInfo
GO

-- try to force primary for multiple records
INSERT INTO ContactInfo (CompanyID,ContactName, IsPrimary) VALUES (1,'Vijay #2', 1), (1, 'Other name #2', 1)
SELECT 'multiple insert with primary', * FROM ContactInfo
GO
```

It is quite convoluted, so I would try to this from the application, as already suggested in one answer.

Comment: you are predinfen isprimary , i want user has to select while inserting & updating. if user deleted isprimary record , you can assign  isprimary top one record.

Comment: The last insert from the tests shows that IsPrimary can be specified by the user. IsPrimary is on the first record, user tries to insert two IsPrimary values. The first record is no longer primary (the second is). I will also add a test for simple insert with IsPrimary to show that IsPrimary can be moved in a deterministic way.

Comment: I have finally seen what the question really wants from us, so I have changed the trigger to act accordingly. I am still not sure that it matches all the scenarios, but it allows to configure how the IsPrimary should behave when it does not exist in the group or there are duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

> for each CompanyID there should be only one row that has IsPrimary =
>   1.

To enforce this create a filtered unique index. The index is filtered on `IsPrimary=1` and is unique on `CompanyID`

Something like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UIX_IsPrimary ON ContactInfo
(
    CompanyID ASC
)
WHERE (IsPrimary=(1))
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) 
ON [PRIMARY]
```

This enforces condition 1

I suggest you enforce conditions 2,3,4 from your application or via a storedp procedure. Triggers often have unanticipated side effects

Comment: that i can prevent the used through constrain , but i need automatically.

Comment: Trigger is the only thing that will do it automatically but they usually turn into a maintenance nightmare.